# setIcon works while setDisabledIcon doesn't - why?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I'd like to set an icon for a JButton for when it's disabled. The problem is, such code:

```
package problemshowcase;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProblemShowcase {
    JFrame frame1 = null;
    JButton btn = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProblemShowcase test = new ProblemShowcase();
        test.makeFrame();
    }

    public void makeFrame()
    {
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(500,500);

        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/test.png")));
        btn.addActionListener(new someListener());

        frame1.getContentPane().add(btn);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    class someListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            JButton foo = (JButton) ev.getSource();

            foo.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Makes the button grey out completely after clicking with no image over it whatsoever. When I change the setDisabledIcon() to setIcon(), however, it shows the correct image both before being clicked and after (though then it's obviously greyed out). What's wrong here?

Comment: post and SSCCE, and use UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon / informationIcon / warningIcon / questionIcon"); instead, then to edit your question here

Comment: You're allowed to use line breaks and indentation in code to make it more clear.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (with line breaks & appropriate indentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it seems JButton (and JToggleButton) simply won't show you the DisabledIcon as long as the "regular" Icon isn't set as well. So the only solution that has crossed my mind if you want to maintain the *non-iconnity* (, which you want if you're coding minesweeper like I am, I suppose) of a button before being clicked is to do it like this:

```
package problemshowcase;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProblemShowcase {
    JFrame frame1 = null;
    JButton btn = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProblemShowcase test = new ProblemShowcase();
        test.makeFrame();
    }

    public void makeFrame()
    {
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(500,500);

        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/test.png")));
        btn.addActionListener(new someListener());

        frame1.getContentPane().add(btn);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    class someListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            JButton foo = (JButton) ev.getSource();
            btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/test.png")));

            foo.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you set the "regular" Icon just before you set the button to be disabled, therefore preventing it to show up at all. You could also place some 1x1 pixel transparent thing there.

Not the most elegant solution but it seems as the only one that works...

Answer (score 1):

> setIcon works while setDisabledIcon doesn't

Both work just fine here.  Click the yellow button to see it turn red.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProblemShowcase {
    JFrame frame1 = null;
    JButton btn = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProblemShowcase test = new ProblemShowcase();
        test.makeFrame();
    }

    public void makeFrame()
    {
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn = new JButton();
        btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.YELLOW,200,40)));
        btn.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.RED,200,40)));
        btn.addActionListener(new someListener());

        frame1.getContentPane().add(btn);

        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    private BufferedImage getImage(Color color, int w, int h) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

    class someListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            JButton foo = (JButton) ev.getSource();

            foo.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, you also use setIcon() which I don't (and don't need as the default look suits me). When you remove the _"btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.YELLOW,200,40)));"_ from your code, it unfortunately doesn't work just like mine doesn't. So do I HAVE to set some icon even if the regular metal one is fine as long as I want setDisabledIcon() to work? setIcon(null) doesn't make setDisabledIcon() work so it looks like this...

Comment: You could always put a transparent image in the `setIcon()` - though that will show with a border around the (invisible) image.

Comment: Yep, but as you say - the border will persist. Does that mean there's no solution to that and I just have to use some icon whether I need it or not?

Comment: Why do you have a completely plain button (no text or icon) at all?

Comment: Because each button represents a cell on Minesweeper grid. Therefore there's just no need to place anything over it.

Comment: Just having checked Windows MineSweeper, I think all phases should have their own icon.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that JButton and JToggleButton require you to call both setIcon() and setDisabledIcon() before the disabled icon will be used. I can think of two ways around this:

1. Call setIcon() with a 1x1 pixel icon that is the same color as the button itself.
2. Subclass JButton or JToggleButton and provide your own functionality.